# different data in different json file. How to load them

Tags: javascript, html, json, css, google-maps-api-3

I have two different json files (*marker.json* and *marker.json0*) which contain different coordinates(latitude and longitude) and I need to load them by renaming *.json0* to *.json* (and obviously the former *.json* is now *.json0*) so that the different data contained in the former *.json0* now *.json* are parsed in the javascript file which handles the ajax request that causes the markers and the infowindow to be displayed on the map.

1. > This is the javascript file that handles the asyncronous loading of
   >   the json array. Moreover there are two functions search and remove.
   >   Both of them are fired whenever the user click the "cerca" or
   >   "cancella" button but their purpose is different. searchAddress parses
   >   the json array inside a loop for so that the markers and the
   >   infowindow are visible while removeAddress deletes them from the map,
   >   now I need to click "cerca" button again to recreate the markers and
   >   infowindow that this time belong to the new json file that on my
   >   webserver I renamed to .json the extension used in the js file. The last edit builds a function to handle the ajax request and at the end of the code I load both of the json files but still the markers go on the same coords.
   >   I have deleted almost all the global variables and I have tried to use arguments to define the variables inside the function. No solution found yet

> edit to js file
>
> ```js
> var map;
>
> function initialize() {
>   var mapOptions = {
>     zoom: 16,
>     center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.898055, 12.515112)
>   };
>   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
>       mapOptions);
> }
>
> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
>
> function Get(url) { 
> var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
> console.log(url);
> arr; 
>
> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
>     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
>         arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
>     }
> }
> xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
> xmlhttp.send();
>
>     function Markers(arr) {
>  var infowindow = [];
>     var marker = [];
>
>  function searchAddress(){
>     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>   console.log(arr);
>             (function(i){ //new line 
>             infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>                 title: arr[i].title,
>     content: arr[i].content
>             });
>             marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
>                     title: arr[i].title,
>      icon: arr[i].icon,
>      size: arr[i].size,
>      coords: arr[i].coords,
>      type: arr[i].type,
>      draggable: false,
>      //map: map,
>                     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
>                     //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,                        
>                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude)
>                 });
>       marker[i].setMap(map) 
>                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
>                     infowindow[i].open(map,this);
>             });
>             })(i); //new line
>     }
> }
>
> // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
> function setAllMap(map) {
>   for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
>     marker[i].setMap(map);
>   }
> }
>
> function removeAddress(){
>  setAllMap(null);
>  prevArr = arr.slice();
> }
>    }  
> markers = Get("http://89.97.214.162/accessibilita    json/marker_json1.json");
> markers.concat(Get("http://89.97.214.162/accessibilita/json/marker_json2.json"));
> ```

---

---

> new javascript errors occured after editing the code:

1. TypeError: markers is undefined
2. ReferenceError: searchAddress is not defined (this error only occurs whene I click on the "cerca" button that whenever clicked should fire the `onclick` event

---

---

2. > this is the first json array which contains latitudes, longitudes, title and content that are parsed in the js array so that the map is able to retrieve them and show the required information (.json)

```html
[
{
"title": "Paolo", 
"latitude": 41.897115,
"longitude": 12.513300,
"content": "Cooperativa fornitrice di servizi sociali,<br/> Viale Eleonora D'Arborea 12<br/> 00162 Roma<br/> <a href='http://www.prassiericerca.com' target='_blank'>Prassi e Ricerca</a>",
"icon": "img/orange-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "Galasso", 
"latitude": 41.897379,
"longitude": 12.513272,
"content": "Penelope e altri servizi <a href='http://www.borghiartistici.com' target='_blank'>Borghi Artistici S.r.l.</a>",
"icon": "img/green-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
........
]
```

3. > this is the second json array containing the new information that are supposed to be loaded whenever this file is renamed from .json1 to .json and the other from .json to .json1
   >   the json file loading is handled in the js file

```html
[
{
"title": "Bar dei Pini", 
"latitude": 41.897115,
"longitude": 12.513300,
"content": "Specialita Gelato Artigianale<br/> Viale Eleonora D'Arborea 12<br/> 00162 Roma<br/> <a href='http://www.prassiericerca.com' target='_blank'>Prassi e Ricerca</a>",
"icon": "img/pink-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "Alimentari San Lorenzo", 
"latitude": 41.897379,
"longitude": 12.513272,
"content": "Specialita Calabresi<a href='http://www.borghiartistici.com' target='_blank'>Borghi Artistici S.r.l.</a>",
"icon": "img/green-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
........
]
```

> As a matter of fact the pages does not need to be reloaded because the two json files are renamed as long as at least one of two is .json

Comment: Such an interesting text formatting...

Comment: what do you mean? however I have approved your edit my friend

Comment: Just a suggestion- this is likely too long a format for a question which will attract a high number of answers, if you are able, try to break it down into a smaller more concise example / query, including the minimum amount of code

Comment: I mean "such an interesting text formatting". Without sarcasm or something else. For example, you use blockquotes for plain text. It is unusual :) And, yes, the edit suggestion is not mine :)

Comment: I took out some of the unimportant material (like the HTML and CSS, and the repetitious JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much simpler if you didn't rename anything. Since `XMLHttpRequest` is a client-side operation, it does not have access to renaming files on the server, such as `json1.json`. What is preventing you from making all the code that gets the JSON into a function with an argument as the URL?

```
function Get(url){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(url);
  var arr; 

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return arr;
}
```

This way, you can get all the files you will ever need. So you could do:

```
markers = Get("http://www.example.com/json1.json");
markers.concat(Get("http://www.example.com/json2.json"));
```

or something like that.

And then a similar thing can be done to your marker code. After it is put in a function, you can submit the `markers` variable as a argument to that function, and it will display them on that map.

Essentially, try to break up your code into functions a) so that it can flow more easily and b) to reuse the same code.

Comment: the markers and markers.concat need to be entered in the beginning of the code I suppose

Comment: No. At the end of the code, since listing them _before_ the function means that the function is `undefined`. They must all be at the very _end_ of the code.

Comment: And then, markers can be passed as an argument to the function that parses Markers.

Comment: Ok I'll try however I expected my question was bad received and as a consequence down voted

Comment: markers and markers.concat are undefinined, maybe they need to be stated as variables I suppose

Comment: I'm sorry -- what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you give me your email, I can continue to help you. Or we could do it in chat

Comment: did it typing your email

Comment: I sent you an email, having copy-and-pasted the address.

Comment: I sent you an email containing the fiddle

Comment: hey I have found something interesting... whether the arr variable is defined outside the get url function the code works and as a consequence both of the files are loaded but if I click on "cerca" which initializes the markers and infowindown and then I clik on "cancella" button that fires the removeAddress function which destroys the markers and then I recreate them again clicking on "cerca"(searchAddress) i create always the same markers so the other json is loaded but I can't use it as I want

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, here is work around, hope that fix your problem.It seems the json attributes title
latitude 
longitude
content
icon
coords
type
 in both the files are same where the lati and longitude value will vary. in such a case why cant we take a pojo with these properties and marshaled the json to this pojo using Gson api. so now the json1 will be in pojo object1 and json2 will be in pojo object2. add these two objects to a list and add the list to JsonParser. this will generate a json again by clubbing the two json files data. now the JsonParser generated data send to java script file.
Hope it is clear.

Comment: could you please add your example in a snippet of code so that it a bit cleared than now, please do not be annoyed by this request...what you have just written put it into a code example could you do it?